# Overriding default str_slug - possible? Laravel-7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7

We have users from TamilNadu and it looks like Laravel's default Str::slug() cannot handle characters like: **தமிழ்** . It simply returns a blank string. This is resulting into 404's on the profile pages of the users.

I'm wondering how do I fix this issue without disturbing the rest of my URLs. I think one way to fix this is to override the default Str::slug() function and check if the original function returns an empty string. If it does, I could comment the first field of as **$title = static::ascii($title)**. then its works. But i don't want to disturb the default Str::slug() method. at the same time don't know how to override it.

**Default Str::slug():**

```
public static function slug($title, $separator = '-')
{
  //$title = static::ascii($title);

  // Convert all dashes/underscores into separator
  $flip = $separator == '-' ? '_' : '-';
  $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($flip).']+!u', $separator, $title);

  // Remove all characters that are not the separator, letters, numbers, or whitespace.
  $title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', mb_strtolower($title));

  // Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
  $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($separator).'\s]+!u', $separator, $title);

  return trim($title, $separator);
}
```

How are you handling this in your app?
Thanks for advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### “str_slug in laravel 8” Code Answer’s

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$slug = Str::slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');
```

str slug laravel

```
$slug = Str::slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');
$slug = Str::slug($request->title);
```

Answer (score 2):

Anything is possible, however I would not recommend overriding Laravel helpers.

Conveniently, the `Str` class uses Laravel `macroable` trait, allowing us to easily extend it.

I suggest to write your own `Str::superSlug()` method to handle slugs in Tamil.

To achieve this, you can add your custom macro to the `boot()` method of your `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    Str::macro('superSlug', function ($title) {
        $slugified = Str::slug($title);

        if ($slugified) {
            return $slugified;
        } else {
            // Your code to handle TamilNadu slugs
        }
    });
}
```

That's it! You can now call your `Str::superSlug();` method anywhere in your code.

Here 's a great video that explains this concept in details:

- https://youtu.be/S8nz1JqbT9M